# Get request parameter in django syndication?

Tags: python, django, feed, syndication

Here is a url containing the hash for a super-secret feed:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/something/feed/12e8e59187c328fbe5c48452babf769c/

I am trying to capture and send the variable `'12e8e59187c328fbe5c48452babf769c'` which is `feed_hash` (acts as a slug to retrieve the particular entry)

Based on the example in **django-syndication**, I've created this simple class in feeds.py

```
class SomeFeed(Feed):
    title = 'feed title '+request.feed_hash #just testing
    link = "/feed/"
    description = "Feed description"

    def items(self):
        return Item.objects.order_by('-published')[:5]

    def item_title(self, item):
        return item.title

    def item_description(self, item):
        return item.content

    # item_link is only needed if NewsItem has no get_absolute_url method.
    def item_link(self, item):
        return 'link'
```

Hence I am wondering, how would I modify this to get a model according to the hash?

At this time I cannot access the `12e8e59187c328fbe5c48452babf769c` in any way. How might I access this and -- in a standard Django way -- create a feed from the retrieved variable (which represents a slug accessing a many-to-many relationship.)

Comment: I think the complex example from the Django feeds documentation is exactly what you want: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/syndication/#a-complex-example You capture the hash in urls.py and map it to a variable, which will be accessable in the feed function.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, set your parameter in django URL dispatcher. Something like:

```
url(r'^feed/(?P<pid>\w+)/$', SomeFeed())
```

Now retrieve and return the hash from the URL using the get_object method on your feed class. After all, get the hash as the second parameter of your method items().

```
class SomeFeed(Feed):
    def get_object(self, request, pid):
        # expect pid as your second parameter on method items()
        return pid 

        # you can also load an instance here and get it the same way on items()
        return SomeFeed.objects.get(pk=pid)

    def items(self, feed):
        # filter your feed here based on the pid or whatever you need..
        return Item.objects.filter(feed=feed).order_by('-published')[:5]
```